# laravel single post not displaying in livewire

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

i am still new to laravel and getting use to some things so please be gentle ,single post not displaying in livewire and I'm not getting any errors.

```
<div>
    <div class="">
        <div class="">
            <img src="" alt="" class="">
            <p class="">{{ $post->title }}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

livewire component

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use App\Models\Post;
use Livewire\Component;

class PostShow extends Component
{
    public $post;

    public function mount(Post $post)
    {
        $this->post = $post;
    }
    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.post-show');
    }
}
```

show blade view

```
<livewire:post-show
    :post="$post"
    />
```

Comment: did you load livewire assets? how is the model binding...by route?